# Shrinking down ext4 partition not working, Oracle VM (W8 host / Ubuntu 13.04 guest)

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, ext4

I've been trying to follow a myriad of directions all to no avail.

I have a 49.4gb drive that is only using 12.1gb of space.  I would like to reduce this drive to 20gb in order for it to be used on a more economical VPS hosting solution (rates vary based on HD space and RAM needed)

[image]

[Here is one set of instructions I followed that did not work.](http://dantwining.co.uk/2011/07/18/how-to-shrink-a-dynamically-expanding-guest-virtualbox-image/)

However the output seemed to work

```
c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage modifyhd "D:\VMBox\EveServers.info
Alpha Live v.3\EveServers.info Alpha Live v.1-disk1.vdi" -compact
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to shrink the `/` logical volume or the block device (virtual disk) that `EVEServer` PV is based on?

If it is a dynamically allocated virtual disk, you don't need to worry about the physical size of the VDI too much.

`VBoxManage modifyhd --compact` is used to shrink the VDI image - which removes blocks that only contains zeros (zero out virtual HDD required beforehand). It will shrink a dynamically allocated image, reduce the physical size of the VDI.

You need to use the `--resize` option to change the capacity of an existing VDI image. However, this works with dynamically allocated disk **ONLY**, and it is capable to expand ONLY, not shrink.

See => [VBoxManage modifyhd](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi)

Comment: Well i ran VBoxManage modifyhd --compact but it didnt seem to effect the displayed size of the disk inside Ubuntu.  My concern is when I try to upload this image to a VPS host, that they will see the disk as being 50 gigs instead of what I would want, 20gb, and charge me for the larger unneeded space....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the displayed size inside Ubuntu, you have no option except copying the partition to a smaller virtual disk. Ubuntu will always display the virtual size of the disk - in your case, it's >= 49.4 GB - and it can not know that it occupies less space on the host operating system.